# Cannot access data from component method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I tried components methods in vue js. My code like this.

```
const Thread = Vue.component('threadpage', function(resolve) {
  $.get('templates/thread.html').done(function(template) {
    resolve({
      template: template,
      data: function() {
        return {
          data: {
            title: "Data Table",
            count: this.GetData
          }
        };
      },
      methods: {
        GetData: function() {
          var data =  {
            username : "newshubid",
            data :  {
              page : 0,
              length : 10,
              schedule : "desc"
            }
          };
          var args = {"data" : JSON.stringify(data)};
          var params = $.param(args);

          var url = "http://example-url";

          var result;

          DoXhr(url, params, function(response){
            result = JSON.parse(response).data;
            console.log("load 1", result);
          });

          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("load 2", result);
            return result;
          }, 1000);
        }
      },
      created: function(){
        this.GetData();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But, when I trying to use `{{ data.count }}` in template. Not showing result what i want. Even I tried return result in `GetData`.

Whats my problem ? And how to access data from methods ? Please help me, i'm a beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the edited code and comments I added below.
You tried to return the result by using `return` in the function from `setTimeout`, which won't help you return value from `GetData`.
Instead, You can just set the value in the callback function of your ajax request.

```
const Thread = Vue.component('threadpage', function(resolve) {
  $.get('templates/thread.html').done(function(template) {
    resolve({
      template: template,
      data: function() {
        return {
          data: {
            title: "Data Table",
            // NOTE just set an init value to count, it will be refreshed when the function in "created" invoked.
            count: /* this.GetData */ {}
          }
        };
      },
      methods: {
        GetData: function() {
          var data =  {
            username : "newshubid",
            data :  {
              page : 0,
              length : 10,
              schedule : "desc"
            }
          };
          var args = {"data" : JSON.stringify(data)};
          var params = $.param(args);

          var url = "http://example-url";

          var result;
          var vm = this;
          DoXhr(url, params, function(response){
            result = JSON.parse(response).data;
            // NOTE set data.count to responsed result in callback function directly.
            vm.data.count = result;
          });
          // NOTE I think you don't need code below anymore.
          // setTimeout(function () {
          //   console.log("load 2", result);
          //   return result;
          // }, 1000);
        }
      },
      created: function(){
        this.GetData();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but my {{ data.count }} not showing. 
Is it true ? using {{ data.count }} ?

Comment: OMG, my mistakes. I forget count : {}. Now its working. Thanks you so much